# Windows batch File - Can't set variable value

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, windows-console

I'm writing a script that should empty the `Recycle.Bin` of all the devices / partitions attached to the computer.

It does this by testing the possible devices available (from a to z letter) excluding the ones that aren't connected.

The script doesn't work properly because of the `IF` statement inside a `FOR` loop. How can I get around this?

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%G IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO (
    SET nodev=none
    fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo "%%G:" | find "Errore:" > nul
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET nodev="%%G:"
    IF "%%G:" NEQ "%nodev%" (
        RD /s /q "%%G:\RECYCLED"
        RD /s /q "%%G:\RECYCLER"
        RD /s /q "%%G:\$Recycle.Bin"
    )
)
```

Comment: `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET %nodev%="%%G:"` Why do you have `%` signs around `nodev`? You don't need them when your variable is on the lefthand side of the `=`.

Comment: Oh, it's a typo, the original one is like this `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET nodev="%%G:"`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"? Please be specific about what's going wrong.

Comment: This line wasn't working properly `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET nodev ="%%G:"` the `nodev` variable was always set to `none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of fsutil.  Also its cleaner code wise.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%G IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO (
    cd /d "%%G:" 2>nul
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        RD /s /q "%%G:\RECYCLED"
        RD /s /q "%%G:\RECYCLER"
        RD /s /q "%%G:\$Recycle.Bin"
    )
)
```

Comment: Now I'm "on the go" but later tonight I'm going to test it, anyway thanks for this different solution, It should even be more compatible than the one I tought.

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. I've just changed the redirection to include standard output as well `CD /D "%%G:" >nul 2>&1` and added the `Setlocal EnableExtensions` environment variable.

Comment: @LMGTFY Sounds great. Glad it helped.  BTW, How old of OSes are you wanting to use this script on?  You may want to add the `setlocal` verification snippet as provided in the `setlocal /?` help text.     1:`VERIFY OTHER 2>nul` 2:`SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS` 3:`IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Unable to enable extensions`.

Comment: If I'm not wrong this script should work flawlessly from Windows 95 up to Windows 8 so I think the check you suggested it's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues.

Firstly you are setting the `nodev` variable with `%`'s around it, which you only use when accessing the variable.

Secondly you need to use delayed expansion to access that variable when inside a `for` loop by using `!`'s instead of `%`'s.

Try this instead

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%G IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO (
SET nodev=none
fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo "%%G:" | find "Errore:" > nul
IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 SET nodev="%%G:"
IF "%%G:" NEQ "!nodev!" (
RD /s /q "%%G:\RECYCLED"
RD /s /q "%%G:\RECYCLER"
RD /s /q "%%G:\$Recycle.Bin"
)
)
```

Comment: Don't forget to use delayedexpansion on the errorlevel var as well. `!ErrorLevel!`

Comment: I think the problem regarding the variable not set is now fixed but while executing the script with Administrator rights (on Windows 7) some error messages appears breaking the script flow:

http://i.imgur.com/Z2hDW.png

Comment: That's probably because you are querying disk info from something that doesn't exist, maybe because only admin permission can request it. I'm guessing though, I'm not sure. Probably best asking that as another question.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I manually type (with Administrator rights) the command `fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo "lettername:" | find "Errore:"` all works as expected.
Can you try the script (changing `Errore:` with your Windows locale one) and report if it works on your computer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LMGTFY  Have you tried using just `cd /d "%%G:"` and checking the errorlevel based upon it?  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @LMGTFY It works fine for me in batch and in cmd, very strange.

Comment: I tought that because it has started showing that error messagges just three days ago, before (the code was slightly different) it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not download a simple program like

```
EmptyRecycleBin.exe
```

Works perfectly

Use google for a link

Comment: I need something compatible even with old OS without using external tools. You know company rules...